# OAuth token refresh in angular app

Tags: angular, oauth, identityserver3, openid-connect, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm using the angular-oauth2-oidc package and IdentityServer3. I'm using the auto refresh option from the angular-oauth2-oidc package in my web app. When the refresh occurs, I'm redirected to my start page (which is the redirectUri in IdentityServer). When I'm now on my detail page, editing data, I will be suddenly transfered back to the main view, when the refresh occurs. Since I use the hash based routing style, I got something like "http://myApp/#/detailView/id123456" when inside my detail view. How do I handle this? I want, at least, stay on the detailView when the refresh occurs and optimum, keep all changed data on the form. I'm missing the "how to" approach to handle this scenario.

Thanks in advance...
Marco...

Comment: Use silent refresh

Comment: I already used silent refresh. In the end, my problem was the hash based routing strategy. After chaging it back to the standard of Angular 5, it worked as expected.

Comment: You can answer your own question (and gain points for it): https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
This will help others with the same problem - your solution is lost in the comment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the routing strategy from "hash based" to the standard Angular routing. After this, it worked as expected.